# Disable Firefox auto update requests

Tags: firefox

Hope I'm writing that in the relevant platform..

I'm working on a script that analyzing requests while browsing sites with Firefox.
I always see requests to aus4.mozilla.org, even after I changed the "Auto-Update" option in the browser to 'Disable' mode.
Does anybody faced with this problem before? How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can turn off Auto Updates on Firefox from Windows:

Run Regedit in windows (Must have admin right)

Expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Policies

If the 2 folders Mozilla and Firefox don't exist under 'Policies'. Create them as per the following:

-Right click on "Policies" folder, Select New > Key then enter "Mozilla"

-Right click on "Mozilla" folder, Select New > Key then enter "Firefox"

-Right click on "Firefox" folder, Select New > DWORD (32 bit) value then enter "DisableAppUpdate"

-Double-click on "DisableAppUpdate" to modify Value data to 1 (hexadecimal). This will stop mozilla from downloading and updating Firefox;

[image: Registry Editor]

It will show "Updates disabled by your system administrator"
[image: About Firefox]

To allow Firefox to update again; Modify the Value Data to 0 .

Answer (score 0):

Weird, the option should work.

Double check that the `app.update.auto` and `app.update.enabled` configuration options are set to `false` (you can do that from `about:config`).

I would suggest using a better method to automate Firefox, for example [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). There are bindings for many programming languages, e.g. for [Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver).

Comment: Interesting, Selenium should automatically disable auto updates (https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.html).
Try opening about:config and search for `aus4` and set the URLs to an empty string or an invalid URL or localhost.

Comment: I believe that this one will work! How can I add this configs to selenium Firefox profile?

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#setPreference-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Python example here: https://gist.github.com/marco-c/17d274e3b6bd7176e0be

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (65.0.2) disabling updates is relatively complicated. Here's the Windows solution:

1. In the firefox.exe directory, create one named **distribution**.
2. Inside **distribution**, place a filed named **policies.json** containing the following:

   ```
   {
       "policies": {
           "DisableAppUpdate": true
       }
   }
   ```

Sources:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1232918

https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md